# Given a type, how can I get the options in an array?

Tags: typescript

In typescript how can I get an array of string options?

```
export type KeyboardType = 'default' | 'email-address' | 'numeric' | 'phone-pad' | 'number-pad' | 'decimal-pad';

const keyboardTypes = x; // ['default', 'email-address', 'numeric', 'phone-pad', 'number-pad', 'decimal-pad']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, since types only exist at compile/transpile time.

You can do the opposite, however, where you have an array of values `keyboardTypes` (make sure to add `as const`) and then define the type `KeyboardType` as the values of that array.

```
const keyboardTypes = ['default', 'email-address', 'numeric', 'phone-pad', 'number-pad', 'decimal-pad'] as const;

export type KeyboardType = typeof keyboardTypes[number];
         // ^? 'default' | 'email-address' | 'numeric' | 'phone-pad' | 'number-pad' | 'decimal-pad'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, there are two ways to go about it:

1. Declare your type KeyboardType first and type your const keyboardTypes:

```
type KeyboardType = 'default' | 'email-address' | 'numeric' | 'phone-pad' | 'number-pad' | 'decimal-pad'
const keyboardTypes: KeyboardType[] = ['default', 'email-address', 'numeric', 'phone-pad', 'number-pad', 'decimal-pad'];
```

2. Declare your const keyboardTypes as const and generate your type from it.

```
const keyboardTypes = ['default', 'email-address', 'numeric', 'phone-pad', 'number-pad', 'decimal-pad'] as const;
type KeyboardType = typeof keyboardTypes[number]
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm getting the `KeyboardType` from react-native and I don't really want to maintain a list of the types separately. It doesn't sound like what I'm asking for is possible